# Estimating a cost of a graph smoothness

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing, computer-vision

For a given video scene, I have a task to evaluate a score for its stability.
I have managed calculate their `deltaX` and `deltaY` vectors of motion of chosen essential features (using affine matrix estimation for every 2 sequenced frames).
Here an example of `deltaX` of two different videos (10 frames each): [link](https://i.ibb.co/jydYHZj/Screen-Shot-2020-04-07-at-14-17-09.png)

We can see that the blue plot represents a more stable scene rather than the orange.

I was wondering how to estimate a cost for each. Obviously the blue plot should have lower cost since is smoother. May some metric regarding the signal frequency? Any suggestions/ recommendations?
Thanks

Comment: In the title, you are talking about estimating a frequency; but in the text you are talking about estimating a cost. So which one is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
It was obvious to me that measuring the cost may be related to the frequency of the signal. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion (which I chose eventually):

For any two neighboring frames (say `a` and `b`) find a projective transformation is estimated (say `M`). Now consider the center of a frame `a` (say `a_c`).

That the "stability score" isthe L2 distance between `a_c`, `(a_c)M` (actually the minimum between this and the `frame_diagonal / 2` in order to limit the score in case of jumps etc.).

[reference](http://www.faculty.idc.ac.il/arik/site/includes/papers/MultiHyperlapsFinal.pdf)